# Python library not recognized in visual studio code even after installation and restarting

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to follow this tutorial for a simple python web application: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6I58WJiKGU. I have copied the code into a python file and tried to run it in VS Code on my Windows computer, but I keep getting an error that the module cannot be found. Here is the beginning of the code:

```
import pywebio
from pywebio.input import input, FLOAT
from pywebio.output import put_text, put_html, put_markdown, put_table
```

And this is the error I get:

```
PS C:\Users\Christos\Documents\Python Scripts> & C:/Users/Christos/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "c:/Users/Christos/Documents/Python Scripts/app.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Christos\Documents\Python Scripts\app.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pywebio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywebio'
```

However, if I go into the terminal within VS Code and use pip install to install the module, I am notified that it has already been installed:

```
PS C:\Users\Christos\Documents\Python Scripts> pip install pywebio
Requirement already satisfied: pywebio in c:\users\christos\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=5.0 in c:\users\christos\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pywebio) (6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: user-agents in c:\users\christos\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pywebio) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ua-parser>=0.10.0 in c:\users\christos\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from user-agents->pywebio) (0.16.1)
```

I tried closing VS code and reopening it, but I continue getting the module not found error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The pip output shows that pywebio is installed for anaconda3.  Therefore, the problem must be that VS Code isn't using anaconda3 as its python interpreter;  it is configured to use some other version of Python that exists on your computer.

Comment: Use this `pip3 install -U pywebio`

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem. I pressed control+shift+p and then typed select interpreter. I clicked on the Python interpreter option and then selected the base python from within anaconda and it is now working.

Answer (score -1):

You have to install the module first using pip in your computer's terminal, not all libraries come with the Python installation. To install PyWebIO you have to open a terminal, command prompt for example and type "pip install pywebio". You will have to restart Visual Studio Code for it to work.

Comment: The question included output from pip that shows the module is already installed.  This isn't the problem.